# Groovy closure $v

Tags: groovy, macros, closures

```
@CompileDynamic
ClassNode buildTemplateClass(ClassNode reference) {
    def methodCount = constX(reference.methods.size())
    def fieldCount = constX(reference.fields.size())

    return  new MacroClass() {

        class Statistics {

            java.lang.Integer getMethodCount() {
                return $v { methodCount }
            }

            java.lang.Integer getFieldCount() {
                return $v { fieldCount }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am not able to get my head around this construct `$v { fieldCount }`. What does it mean and why is this needed here ? For a full reference of what the code is doing refer [here](http://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#_macroclass).

In case it is not clear what the constX method does refer [here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.5.1/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/ast/tools/GeneralUtils.html#constX-java.lang.Object-).

Comment: Could you elaborate on "that i have".  Assuming you didn't write it yourself and forgot all about it: where does it come from?  Is the rest of the class somewhere public (can you link it)?

Comment: I have edited the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's written in your [doc](http://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#_macroclass), `$v` used **inside a macro** for substituting an expression

> In order to substitute any expression inside the macro we need to use the $v method. $v receives a closure as an argument, and the closure is only allowed to substitute expressions, meaning classes inheriting org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.Expression.